# Workflow settings : In Select a workflow template option missing my workflow name SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, workflow

Please check the screen shot.Select workflow template dropdown missing my workflow name
[image]
[image]

Comment: are you have list workflow or reusable workflow ?

Comment: Yes list workflow . So why next button appear ?

Comment: I want to uncheck the option Require Manage Lists Permissions to start the workflow.but its showing alert select workflow template name.

Comment: where's this option ? are you try to run SharePoint workflow Manual ? list workflow not show as template as i told you in my below answer , should you elaborate more please to can help you

Comment: Please see on 2nd img  there is start option bottom of lift side i want to change it and save this  changes but when i click on next button Alert message pop up to "select workflow template name"

Comment: if your issue is related to change the starting option for you custom list workflow it's should be from SharePoint Designer > open it from SharePoint designer > at workflow settings > change the startup option , please don't hesitate to ask me if you have any other query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44476/discussion-between-m-qassas-and-admin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This because you have created a list workflow, not reusable workflow.

To check the list workflow related to your list that you have created from SharePoint Designer.

- Got to your list > from the above ribbon > workflow settings.

[image]

Check also [Difference between List WorkFlow Vs Reusable WokFlow Vs Site WorkFlow](https://skdeveloper.wordpress.com/2013/09/20/differance-between-list-workflow-vs-reusable-wokflow-vs-site-workflow/)

**[Update]**

To change starting option for a custom list workflow

- OpenSharePoint Designer > Open Site > Workflow > Edit workflow > from right > select your start option (Manual - At item added - add item updated)

Comment: Yes  i am going same way to open this page.I want to uncheck the option  Require Manage Lists Permissions to start the workflow.but its showing alert  select template name.